# Customize WPF Button Style Programmatically

Tags: wpf, vb.net, button, styles, customization

In a WPF project, using the following code to customize a button in the Window_Loaded event:

```
Dim style As Style = New Style
style.TargetType = GetType(Button)
Dim trigger As DataTrigger = New DataTrigger
trigger.Value = "OK"

'set binding
Dim bi As New Binding
Dim pp As New PropertyPath("Content")
bi.Path = pp
bi.RelativeSource = RelativeSource.Self
trigger.Binding = bi ' New Binding(pp.Path)
Dim setter As Setter = New Setter
setter.Property = Button.BackgroundProperty
setter.Value = Brushes.Red
trigger.Setters.Add(setter)

'clear the triggers
style.Triggers.Clear()
style.Triggers.Add(trigger)
btn_Step.Style = style
```

It compiles okay, but no noticeable change to the button.  How can I get this to be applied?

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't do this in xaml?

Comment: Thnx for responding.  The answer is that the button doesn't exist until run-time (it's created dynamically/programmatically).

Comment: @swabygw, I suggest to declare button style in window.resources, debug it on some test button and then apply style from resources to dynamic buttons (smth like `btn_Step.Style = (Style)Resources["MyButtonsStyle"]`)

Comment: Okay - I thought about doing that, but then I also thought that must be a way to program it, too.  But your suggestions means that there might not be a way to program it, so I'll try that route, too.

Comment: I tried your idea and it works in XAML, but can't get it to switch in code with: btn_Step.Style = Style.Resources("MyButton"), although I have placed the template in the Windows.Resource correctly.  Do you know what the correct command is?

Comment: @ASh Scratch that - I was using it in my class code and had to just point it back to the main window.  If you post this as an answer, I'll mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it with code - here's my final solution:

```
Public Function CreateStyle(ByVal clr1 As SolidColorBrush, ByVal clr2 As SolidColorBrush)

    Dim st As New Style
    st.TargetType = GetType(Button)
    Dim se0 As New Setter
    se0.Property = Button.OverridesDefaultStyleProperty
    se0.Value = True
    st.Setters.Add(se0)
    Dim se1 As New Setter
    se1.Property = TemplateProperty

    Dim ct As New ControlTemplate
    'Reference: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ddb7fd77-dea1-40f5-a5b7-30d35ecda70e/creating-a-control-template-with-code-behind?forum=wpf
    ct.TargetType = GetType(Button)
    Dim fef0 As New FrameworkElementFactory(GetType(Border))
    fef0.Name = "Border"
    fef0.SetValue(Border.BorderThicknessProperty, New Thickness(1))
    fef0.SetValue(Border.BorderBrushProperty, Brushes.Black)
    ct.VisualTree = fef0

    Dim fef1 As New FrameworkElementFactory(GetType(ContentPresenter))
    fef1.SetValue(HorizontalAlignmentProperty, HorizontalAlignment.Center)
    fef1.SetValue(VerticalAlignmentProperty, VerticalAlignment.Center)
    fef0.AppendChild(fef1)

    Dim tr0 As New Trigger
    tr0.Property = Button.IsMouseOverProperty
    tr0.Value = True
    Dim se2 As New Setter
    se2.TargetName = "Border"
    se2.Property = Button.BackgroundProperty
    se2.Value = clr1
    tr0.Setters.Add(se2)
    ct.Triggers.Add(tr0)

    Dim tr1 As New Trigger
    tr1.Property = Button.IsMouseOverProperty
    tr1.Value = False
    Dim se3 As New Setter
    se3.TargetName = "Border"
    se3.Property = Button.BackgroundProperty
    se3.Value = clr2
    tr1.Setters.Add(se3)
    ct.Triggers.Add(tr1)

    se1.Value = ct
    st.Setters.Add(se1)

    Return st

End Function
```